# Table Reference Format and Hyperlinks

Tags: tables, numbering

I'm using hyperref package and refer to hundreds of tables from the appendix.  My labels for tables look like: `\label{table:some-numbers}`.  I then refer to it from the main text as `\ref{table:some-numbers}`.  What I get is a lot of identically-looking hyperlinks in the PDF, with the same visible text like A.3 -- even though the specific table is actually A.145 and the hyperlink in fact takes me there!  Why does the visible text in the hyperlink box looks the same for many tables, as if it were a section number, not the table number, and how do I make it coincide with the actual table number?

Comment: This should work. Construct a minimal example to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you put the `\label` before the caption which actually labels the last caption, section or other label-able item. Make sure that you put it after the `\caption`. I think the hyperlinks still work because they create an anchor wherever `\label` is used.

Comment: exactly, this was the case of `label` preceding `caption`.